# Laravel - Eloquent - Return Where Related Count Is Greater Than

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables.

Products
Brands

Im trying to return top 10 brand models with the most products.

I've tried.

```
Product::select('brand', DB::raw('count(brand) as count'))->groupBy('brand')->orderBy('count','desc')->take(10)->get();
```

But that doesn't return the hole model and only returns

- Brand
- Count

I've also tried

```
 return $brands = Brand::whereHas('products', function($q) {
           $q->count() > 10;
       })->get();
```

But I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'brands.id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products`
>   where `brands`.`id` = `products`.`brand`)

**My Brand Model**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','brand');
    }
```

**My Product Model**

```
public function manuf()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand','brand');
    }
```

Comment: show your relationship please

Comment: Added :) @KhanShahrukh

Comment: is you brand table called `brand` or `brands`? It could be that you need to explicitly tell laravel what your table name is to stop it pluralizing it.

Comment: My table is called Brands

Answer (score 40):

try this:

```
$brands = Brands::has('products', '>' , 10)->with('products')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, this work for me in Laravel 5.4 :)

Comment: any idea if 10 is a value of brands table's column ?

Comment: Could you share the RAW query for this?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to accomplish this with the [`withCount` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) if you're using at least Laravel 5.3:

```
Brand::withCount('products')->orderBy('products_count', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
```

Where `products` is the name of your relation. This will give you a new field in your query, `products_count` that you can order by.

Comment: This would only display the Product model and I'm only after the Brand model.

Comment: This translates to SQL as `SELECT *, COUNT('brand') as count FROM products GROUP BY brand ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10;`. From your question, that seems like exactly what you're wanting. If that's not the case, please clarify the question.

Comment: In my question I clarified by asking "Im trying to return top 10 brand models with the most products." apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Updated answer. Note that it will only work on 5.3 or above.

Comment: It would be better to add a raw query instead of this since it does not answer the question and its inefficient.