# getting the count of a relationship and filtering based on that count with whereBetween

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am doing a search query and this is what I am trying to do:

The model Project has many bids, I want to get the count of these bids and filter projects based on that using whereBetween.

I tried doing this:

```
                $query->withCount('bids')
                    ->whereBetween('bids_count', [5, 10]);
```

but it's telling me that column bids_count does not exist

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show your table Schema

Comment: I don't see how that's going to help. The table does not have the column bids_count, it should be returned by withCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example , to get the brands have more than 10 product

`$brands = Brands::has('products', '>' , 10)->with('products')->get();`

or 

`Brand::withCount('products')->orderBy('products_count', 'DESC')->take(10)->skip(5)->get();`

you can use take and skip for between

Check this 
[Laravel - Eloquent - Return Where Related Count Is Greater Than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584706/laravel-eloquent-return-where-related-count-is-greater-than)

Comment: or you can use  has('products', '>' , 5)->has('products', '<' , 10)
but you have to check the sql generated query to check if its optimized